# Vue.js 3: props type validation with custom type

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vue-component, vuejs3

I am developing a single page application using Vue.js 3 and Typescript.

The problem affects a view and a single file component. `People.vue` retrieves data from the backend and displays it in multiple `PersonRow.vue` components using `v-for`. Although data property types are explicitly defined, I get a warning in the browser console:
`[Vue warn]: Invalid prop: Type check failed for prop "person". Expected Person, got Object`

Everything is working fine and I could change the property type in `PersonRow.vue` to `Object` to get rid of the warning but I would like to have type checks working correctly.

**`People.vue`**

```
<template>
  <div class="container">
    <PersonRow v-for="person in people" :key="person.id" :person="person" />
  </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { defineComponent } from 'vue'
import { Person, getPeople } from '../services/person'
import PersonRow from '@/components/PersonRow.vue'

export default defineComponent({
  components: {
    PersonRow
  },
  data () {
    return {
      people: new Array<Person>()
    }
  },
  mounted () {
    getPeople().then(
      response => {
        this.people.push(...response)
      })
  }
})
</script>
```

**`PersonRow.vue`**

```
<template>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">{{ person.givenName }}</div>
    <div class="col">{{ person.familyName }}</div>
  </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { defineComponent } from 'vue'
import { Person } from '../services/person'

export default defineComponent({
  props: {
    person: {
      type: Person,
      required: true
    }
  }
})
</script>
```

**`person.ts`**

```js
export class Person {
  constructor (id: number, givenName: string, familyName: string) {
    this.id = id
    this.givenName = givenName
    this.familyName = familyName
  }

  id: number;
  givenName: string;
  familyName: string;
}

export async function getPeople (): Promise<Person[]> {
  const response = await fetch('https://api.example.com/people')
  return await response.json() as Person[]
}
```

Answer (score 41, accepted):

[Annotating Props](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/typescript-support.html#annotating-props)

```js
export default defineComponent({
  props: {
    person: {
      type: Object as PropType<Person>,
      required: true
    }
  }
})
```

### Deeper dive

Yes, the [docs](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/component-props.html#type-checks) says: *In addition, `type` can also be a custom constructor function and the assertion will be made with an `instanceof` check*

But in order to make it work the object passed into the prop must be created with `new Person()` constructor. And the problem is your `getPeople ()` function is not creating array of `Person` instances - it's just type casting array of regular JS objects created with `json()` to `Person[]`. Typecasting don't change the runtime type of the object...

Comment: Note that you might have to `import type { PropType } from 'vue'` to use `PropType`

Comment: As the original question asks for an Array type, you can do that using `Array as PropType<Person[]>` instead of `Object as`

Answer (score -9):

"Person" is not a type. Types can be Array, Object, String, Number, Boolean, Function. So type checks work correctly.

Comment: The docs state that custom types are possible: https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/component-props.html#type-checks

Comment: But they mean JavaScript classes. If your TypeScript class is transpiled at build time, for Vue it's just Object at runtime (when prop typecheck happens)

Comment: Also docs say *validate that the value of the `author` prop was created with `new Person`* but your `getPeople` function is not calling `Person` constructor, it's just casting regular JS objects deserialized from JSON to `Person[]`

Comment: Thanks for mentioning that. `PropType<T>` allowed me to change my type definition from `class` to `interface` which removes all the overhead of unused constructors while type inference and validation are still working.